# Changing text case using PHP regex functions

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to implement a customer requirement where they can use arbitrary regular expressions to match patterns in arbitrary text and then modify the case of some or all of the matches. An example would be (sp)([\d]+) which is a search expression that finds all instances of the letter combination "sp" followed by one or more digits. The corresponding expression would then uppercase the sp as follows: \U$1$2

We implement support for regular expressions via a web interface that POSTS to a PHP script which uses the preg_match() and preg_replace() PHP perl-compatible regex functions to match and change the input respectively.

I've tried using preg_replace_callback instead as it passes an array of matches to callback that you write yourself, but the problem is that without knowing the match and replace patterns, as well as the input text being modified in advance, as far as I can tell we have no way to reliably determine which match came from which component of the regex, and therefore which match needs to be uppercased or lowercased.

Has anyone ever tried anything similar and had success?

Thanks!

Comment: Letting clients define their own expressions is a bit risky. Read about [ReDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). If it's an option, try to give predefined regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, you can make it an application requirement that the word matching regex shouldn't contain groups but using `$match[0]` ensures that the entire word match is upper cased.

```php
function _UpperCase_Preg_Matches($match){
    return strtoupper($match[0]);
}

$subject = "Item sp001 and item sp002 are good.";

print preg_replace_callback( "/\bsp\d+\b/i", _UpperCase_Preg_Matches, $subject);
```

Output:

```
Item SP001 and item SP002 are good.
```

---

In an application I've build before we have a regex for upper casing words which takes a series of small rules and joins them all together.

The small rules would be something like `PC\d{6}`, `LAP\d{6}` and `SERV\d{3}`. They would then be joined together inside the followin regex `/\b(?: rule1 | rule2 | rule3 )\b/i`. And the matches get passed into a callback to be upper cased.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, the regex I gave above was just an example, we need to be able to handle arbitrary regexes, we don't know what ones they're going to use in advance.

Comment: You could get your users to define an Uppercase regex and a Lowercase regex and just do to calls to preg_replace_callback with each rule. You might be trying to over engineer your solution.